# Problem to read old books

Tags: evince

Does anybody have any idea how to configure Evince or any other document viewer so that the last could quickly open and leaf through some old facsimile? I mean the books which were written a couple of hundred years ago and well kept in the Internet Archive (American Libraries.) Thanks. Igor

Comment: Provide some information as to the issue, please.

Comment: What format is the books provided in?

Comment: What do mean by "quickly open"? That's a function of the hardware, which you haven't described.

Comment: Well, I download those books in PDF format. When it was Windows 7 and Foxit Reader, I could open & read the stuff as I do this site. Now, it's Ubuntu 18.04.2, Evince open books a bit slower, but the problem is in slow opening every subsequent page of a book. So, how to work with several books at a time, when I have to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, Foxit on Windows 7 and Foxit on Ubuntu are things very different.
So, I have to amend my previous answer and write the following.
Okular and Evince, both downloaded by Synaptic, proved better. 
Okular is good for old books in pdf format, and Evince for modern pdf stuff.
Add to that the problem of removing Foxit, notwithstanding all articles to the contrary. Foxit was removed only when I reinstalled Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I found the only way to read those old books: install Foxit Reader. 
https://www.itsmarttricks.com/how-to-install-foxit-pdf-reader-in-ubuntu-18-04/
However, all commands recommended by this link are to be preceded by "sudo."
At least, that works on my Ubuntu 18.04.2.